# Как сделать содержимое блока по центру в CSS?

Tags: html, css

Есть сырая форма авторизации, как сделать ее содержимое в центре блока?

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">

  <h3>LOG IN</h3>

  <p>
    <input name="mail" type="mail" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input name="password" type="password" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input name="button" type="button" />
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
body {background: #999}

.login {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}

.login h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.login p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">

  <h3>LOG IN</h3>

  <p>
    <input name="mail" type="mail" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input name="password" type="password" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <input name="button" type="button" />
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
p input{text-align:center;margin:0px auto; padding:0px;}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  
  <h3>LOG IN</h3>
  
  <p>
    <input name="mail" type="mail"/>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <input name="password" type="password"/>
  </p>
  
  <p>
    <input name="button" type="button"/>
  </p>
  
</div>
```